# PHP Build an associative array from for-loop

Tags: php, associative-array

I have a requirement to generate following associative array from a for-loop .

```
Array ( [0] => 
    Array ( 
            [id] => 1 
            [value] => 6

        ) [1] => 
        Array ( 
                [id] => 2 
                [value] => 7 

        ) [2] => 
        Array ( 
                [id] => 3 
                [value] => 8 

        ) 
    )
```

Tried this code

```
 $total_pages = 3;
 $pagination = array();
 for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {
                $pagination[]['id'] = $i;
                $pagination[]['value'] = $i + 5;
            };
```

I have tried this code but cannot able to generate an associative array. Not sure about how to do it. Please help me to solve this issue. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$total_pages = 3;
 $pagination = array();
 for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {
    $arr_temp = array();
    $arr_temp['id'] = $i;
    $arr_temp['value'] = $i + 5;
    $pagination[] = $arr_temp;
};
print_r($pagination);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [value] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [value] => 7
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [value] => 8
        )

)
```

**[Wording Demo](https://eval.in/175135)**

Answer (score 3):

You are generating a sub array on each iteration if you leave the `[]`, if you provide an index instead it will work:

```
$total_pages = 3;
$pagination = array();
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {
  $pagination[$i - 1]['id'] = $i;
  $pagination[$i - 1]['value'] = $i + 5;
};
```

Comment: output will start from array index 1

Comment: Thanks, hadn't noticed.

Comment: Why would you over-complicate such a simple thing, like `$pagination[] = array('id' => $i, 'value' => $i+5);`?

Comment: It just came up on top of my head, no particular reason, your answer is better and shorter.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the easiest option:

```
$total_pages = 3;
$pagination = array();
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {
  $pagination[] = array('id' => $i, 'value' => $i+5);
};
```

... and also the shortest, if I check other answers.